# $ sign in PHP - is there a way around?

Tags: php, syntax

I feel unconfortable about the way I have to put $ before every occurence of each variable in PHP. I wonder if there's any solution that would allow to omit it.

I guess there could be some available solution for some IDE that automatically place sigils before all the variables. In addition I would like to hear advices about IDE that suits this idea just fine, that is have some embedded means like macros. Which one should I choose? I tend to decide in favor of UltraEdit.

Comment: You could write everything as functional code and never use local variables or class members.

Comment: You can also use a constant yet be aware you should only do this on 
"variables" that MAY/MUST NOT CHANGE, be aware use it correctly and nothing is wrong the way to bypass the '$' is simple: Stop with PHP

Comment: @MikeM. Then it wouldn't be variable.

Comment: @CarlMarkham I said "variables" for a reason ;) anyways I haven't posted the full comment so I just edited it :D

Comment: @Dan Then use it... But with `$` as PHP is...

Comment: @murgatroid99, that's hardly an option...

Comment: @Dan It *is* an option. Most algorithms can be written by composing functions. Whether it's a better option than simply putting up with the strangeness of PHP syntax is your decision.

Comment: Please stop editing your question with new questions. The original one was enough. The idea of removing the $ is not thought through. And even if someone cook up some batcrazy stuff, it would be horrible to work with for anyone else used to the syntax, not to talk about code analysers, linters and etc. avoid tying yourself to a IDE to tightly

Comment: Take a look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/208605/do-sigils-make-source-code-easier-to-read it might change you mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm, no. That's part of the **PHP** syntax. Not really any way around it.

In response to the edit:

There would be no way for the **IDE** to know what is a variable and what isn't. I suppose you could use your own symbol in replace of a `$` and then replace all instances of that with a `$`. You could even compile the **PHP** script with the same method using another language that you are comfortable with.

However, the best answer would be to either get comfortable with it, or use another server side language. You could try and circumnavigate the syntax but in the end you are only really using more time to do so.

There are plenty to choose from. I know a lot of **PHP** devs that have migrated to Ruby for the syntax alone.

Comment: There isn't really an "answer" needed for this a comment is enough.

Comment: This is an answer. He asked if he could omit the `$` sign and I said no. I also gave a reason.

Comment: I believe there must be some kind of solution. In fact, I can think of such a solution myself, it's just that I wanted to check if there's any available.

Comment: @Dan If you can think of such a solution then why ask if there are any solutions?.

Comment: @CarlMarkham, because I'm not in favour of bicycle invention.

Comment: Then you could have added the fact that you may have a solution to the question followed by an explanation of said solution. That way people could discuss your methodology as well as provide their own suggestions.

Comment: Okay, I'll add that to the OP

Answer (score 2):

That is part of the PHP syntax. You can always use another language if you find it annoying.

PHP is based on Perl and in Perl the `$` sign signifies scalars (`@` signifies arrays and `%` signifies associative arrays). PHP uses `$` for all types.

Such symbols are called [*sigils*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: This is the best answered solution, this should be the answer "until someone else posts a better one"